# Query on Secondary Index with large text

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a table like below,

```
CREATE TABLE log (    
"date" text,     
"timestamp" timestamp, "message" text,"module" text,"userId" text,
primary key ("date","timestamp")) with clustering order by ("timestamp" DESC);
```

Where I create the SASI index on the 'message' column, which has more characters, we can expect around 250 characters in every log message column. Indexing on a column with more number of characters will it create an impact in performance?

```
select * from log where date = '20180223' AND message LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [presentation from 2016th](https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/sasi-cassandra-on-the-full-text-search-ride-duyhai-doan-datastax-c-summit-2016), SASI uses Guava's `ConcurrentSuffixTree` implementation that allows to build [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) to perform effective search.  I don't know about Guava's implementation, but theoretically during the indexing used space and execution time will grow linear to string's length.  But because indexed tex requires more space to store than text itself, there could be some overhead when performing search as well.

P.S. But everything should be tested on live system.